# Weka does not have NominalToNumeric Filter

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, weka, k-means

In my dataset, there are 3 nominal attributes that I want to convert them to be numeric for the purpose of `k-mean clustering algorithm`. In Weka, the only filter I found is `NominalToBinary` and when I use it creates new attributes corresponding to the number of nominal values there. Is that normal? Why there is no `NominalToNumeric` is Weka?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it what [nominal attribute](http://www.psy.gla.ac.uk/~steve/best/ordinal.html) is. It means that there is no ordering in your attribute values. Can you say that *male > female*. Therefore you should change your nominal attributes to binary ones using NominalToBinary filter.

If your attributes are not nominal but Ordinal; then, you need to use custom transformation. This custom transformation is hard to achieve and different for every data set.

I suggest using [RenameNominalValues](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/RenameNominalValues.html) to give your ordinal attributes to numeric values, then using a text editor to change attribute type from nominal to numeric.

For example change Hot, Mild, Cool, Cold to 40, 20, 10, 0 using RenameNominalValues, then use text editor. 
But as you can see my values are completely arbitrary and may not be a very good choice.